# Using WordPress as a backend for an app?

Tags: android, wordpress, wordpress-json-api

I'm creating an app which has a list with content (Images, text...) which is going to come from the Internet (my website) . I want to be able to update and add / edit content easily.

I'm thinking about using WordPress as the backend, and then use a HTML parser such as jSoup to get the text / images etc. from the WordPress site and put it into the list & wherever I need it in the app. I could easily add / update / delete content, plus it is also accessible in a normal browser.

Good idea ?(why? / why not?) Anyone ever tried it? Possible alternatives?

Comment: Use the RSS feed and I guess you could do it. But to say it's a good idea... probably not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plugins available to create a REST API from your WordPress site, like this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/. I think that might be useful!